# Cost effective way to generate THz frequency

Tags: rf, multiplier

Kicking around some ideas here as how to multiply a relatively low RF GHz frequency to the THz range.  Would simply using a cheap 4400MHz RF signal generator and a couple inline RF frequency multipliers do, or would this distort the resulting wave?

Of course the best manner to implement would be with femto-second lasers but well that is rather expensive for a hobbyist.

I guess my question is do RF waves stay "true" when being multiplied or is there some sort of distortion that will occur?

Comment: Use an LED - visible light is about 400 THz.

Comment: Have you found an rf frequency multiplier capable of generating terahertz output in your price range?

Comment: Not a bad idea but the THz range you have to make use of light pulses.  Maybe a low cost femtosecond clock and then translate to some sort of pulse?  There is a cheap way to this just have to think outside the box.

Answer (score 2):

There has to be distortion happening, otherwise there would be no multiplication.

A frequency multiplier works by generating harmonics through distortion and then selecting one of the harmonics with a frequency selective circuit.

How much the output signal is distorted will depend on how selective the frequency selective circuit is. You could also add post filtering to clean up the signal more.

Comment: How would one then keep the signal amplification more precise?  Obviously the higher the amplification the more the distortion.  Would it then be worthwhile to add in a filter after every amplifier? I am trying to achieve very precise THz signals. Maybe this is not possible in a cost effective manner.

Comment: Well in multiplication you want more distortion, because you want to maximize the energy in the harmonics you're generating. Once you have the harmonics you filter them to get a clean sine wave at one of the harmonics. I've seen multipliers that generate 450 MHz from 150 MHz by using a varactor and tuned cavities, maybe the same could be done at 1 THz but I haven't really looked into it.

Comment: @Robert292 "Amplify" is the wrong word here. You mean "multiply", as in: frequency multiplication.

Comment: It's a lot easier to generate 100 THz for 25 cents. ;) LOL

Answer (score 0):

You can't get amplifiers in the THz range; you can generate THz signals using non-linear elements (basically diodes) -- note that this is quite inefficient (worse than -10 dB per stage), and needs filtering to eliminate the baseband and other unwanted harmonics. That also removes the 'distortion' (it's the distortion of the baseband that *generates* the THz signals).

Equipment to process THz signals costs in the $100k range.

Comment: So the resulting frequency will be inefficient and large but un-precise.  That makes sense.  For this experiment I am looking for precision to whole numbers only.  I may have to look into building some sort of diode based multiplier then.